# how to delete an app that is a device admin app that is preventing device admin app deactivation

Tags: android, device-admin

how to delete an app that is a device admin app that is preventing device admin app deactivation?
when i try to deactivate it, the deactivate device administrator button is greyed out.

I tried resetting the phone, which was prevented as well, clearing data, cache is blocked too. I cant access the entire Samsung account setting page.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using **Safe Mode**?

To activate it:

> 1. Turn the phone off
> 2. Press and hold the Power button until the Samsung logo appears, then >release
>
>    - Note: the Power button is located on the right edge
> 3. With the Samsung logo on the screen, press and hold the Volume Down button
>
>    - Note: the Volume Down button is located on the left edge
> 4. Once Safe mode appears in the lower-left corner of the screen, release the Volume Down button

[Source](https://help.republicwireless.com/hc/en-us/articles/115013259628-How-to-Enable-Safe-Mode-on-Samsung-Galaxy-Series-Phones)

> Safe mode is a diagnostic mode on your phone that helps you troubleshoot device issues such as slow speeds or frequent crashes. Safe mode disables your third-party apps to help you determine whether your issue is caused by one of the apps or your operating system.

[Source](https://www.avast.com/c-how-to-turn-off-safe-mode-android#:%7E:text=Safe%20mode%20is%20a%20diagnostic%20mode%20on%20your%20phone%20that,apps%20or%20your%20operating%20system.)

To **deactivate** Safe Mode just **restart the phone normally**.